# Ethereum event not showing up but function completing

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts

I have the following contract:

```
Contract Store{

    event Purchase(address buyer, int item_id);

    struct Product {
        string name;
        uint price;
        string desc;
        uint quantity;
        bool enabled;
    }

    mapping (address => int) balances;

    function buyProduct(uint id) returns(bool){
        if(products[id].quantity <= 0){ return false; }

        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender] - int(products[id].price);
        products[id].quantity--;
        Purchase(msg.sender, id);
        return true;
      }

}
```

When I use web3 to purchase a product with `Store.buyProduct`, the product purchase is made, but the event doesn't fire on the front-end.  Here is my event watcher code:

```
var eventFilter = Store.deployed().Purchase({from: "0xe02b4fc50f429624937e9425e1243292857291e2"}, {fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest'});

eventFilter.watch(function(error, event){
    console.log('hai');
    console.log(event);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Argh. It just started working, I was passing a `uint` to the event but it was expecting an `int`.